# Enumerable.Where - How To Read The API

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand specifically why it is neccessary to have this `Where<TSource>`

What does the type straight after `Where` tell you?

I understand the 'this' concept which means its an extension method but cannoth understand the type after Where

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to read up on generics? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Func<TSource, bool>` is a pointer to a function which takes `TSource` as parameter and returns boolean. For example if you had the following function:

```
public bool Foo(SomeType abc)
{
    return abc.SomeProperty == "123";
}
```

you could pass it as argument to the Where method if you had a list of `SomeType`:

```
SomeType[] values = ...
var result = values.Where(Foo);
```

You could also use an anonymous function which avoids you the need to declare another function explicitly:

```
SomeType[] values = ...
var result = values.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == "123");
```

---

UPDATE:

I seem to have misunderstood the question. The type after the name of the function `Where<TSource>` indicates a [generic function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) definition. It indicates that this function has a generic argument which can be of any type. So for example when you write:

```
SomeType[] values = ...
var result = values.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == "123");
```

`TSource` equals `SomeType` and the compiler is capable of automatically inferring it from the delegate. You could specify it explicitly but it's too much of a writing:

```
SomeType[] values = ...
IEnumerable<SomeType> result = values.Where<SomeType>(x => x.SomeProperty == "123");
```

Comment: My question is not about the params or the return type - My question is why you need a type here'Where<TSource>'

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw, that's because it is a generic method definition. `TSource` indicates the generic type.

Comment: Generic type of what?Input or output? And isnt this covered in the type of the params/return type?

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw, both input and output as `TSource` is used in both the input parameters and the result parameter. The reason you don't need to specify it when calling the method `values.Where(...` is because the compiler can infer it from the argument, but you could also specify it explicitly: `values.Where<SomeType>(...`

Comment: Thanks - Make more sense - I cannot see how you would ever need to specify this type explicitly however.  Can you post an example generic method which you are required to specify the type explicitly for and which the compiler cannot infer it?  Is it possible

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw, yes absolutely, the compiler can infer the generic type only if it appears somewhere in the input parameters. Take for example this definition: `public T Foo<T>() { ... }`. Now in order to invoke this function you always need to specify the generic parameter: `string result = Foo<string>();`, you cannot simply write `string result = Foo();` as it won't compile. In this case the compiler is not capable of inferring the generic type as it doesn't appear among the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The type in `<...>` after `Where` is a declaration of *generic type parameter*. The `Where` method is generic which means that some of the types involved in its type declaration can be provided when the method is used. In C#, this is called *generics*.

The `<...>` is a place where you declare types that the caller needs to specify when using your method. It is, in some way, similar to declarations of parameters

- When using parameters, you say that the caller needs to give you some values and you give them names (e.g. `source` and `predicate`).
- When writing generic method, you say that the caller needs to give you some type and you give the type a name (e.g. `TSource`) that you can use in the method declaration and body.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to your question would be for type safety and IntelliSense while programming. (All the benifits that Generics provide).

`LINQ to Objects` works on Extension Methods defined in a type named `Enumerable`. Mostly, they deal with type `IEnumerable<T>`.

So, for example, when you want it to operate on a `List<String>`, the `Where<TSource>` becomes `Where<String>`. And C# 3.0 type inferance comes into picture so that you dont have to explicitly specify the `String` part. Since, the compiler knows you are working with `IEnumerable<T>`.

To sumarrize, when you use Where method on a List, the method expects an `IEnumerable<String>` and a `Predicate` that takes `String` to filter on input sequence as an input and provides with an `IEnumerable<String>` as an output.